# JQuery visibility controls not working on LockerService

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service

Very straightforward. Works [without LockerService](https://i.imgur.com/i0wzqmH.gifv), doesn't work [with LockerService.](https://i.imgur.com/hFkTwiB.gifv)

EDIT : It seems to be [less broken in Sandbox](https://i.imgur.com/Rb5DoTT.gifv), which is on Version 10 of Summer '16, compared to Version 9.5 of Summer '16 but definitely still broken.

TestApp2.app

```
<aura:application >
  <ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.jquery}"/>
    <div aura:id="testdiv" id="testElem">  
        Visibility test.
    </div>
    <ui:button buttonTitle="Test button" class="button" label="Test" press="{!c.toggle}"/>
</aura:application>
```

TestApp2Controller.js

```
({
    toggle : function(component, event, helper) {
        $("#testElem").slideToggle("slow");
    }
})
```

Comment: Jason, which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: @JFParadis I am using JQuery 2.2.4

Answer (score 0):

Works for me on Locker in my sandbox, sort of. The text slides away and comes back on one single button press but this is definitely more than you're getting in Locker. Is this in a sandbox, a dev edition org, or production? Sandboxes are all on Summer '16 Patch 10 while most other orgs are still on Patch 9.5. So try in a sandbox or wait for Patch 10 and try again, then debug if it's still not behaving how you want it to. If this is actively affecting a production org then disable Locker on it until it's patched.

Comment: This is on a dev org, I guess I'll try it out in a sandbox, thanks! Also, where could I find information about which orgs are on which patch?

Comment: There is info here: http://trust.salesforce.com/trust/instances where after you click on an instance name, the patch level is visible in the upper right of the screen beside the RSS icon.

Comment: Now that I test it in a sandbox org, I am getting the same result you are getting. Still seems like unintended behavior though..

Comment: Indeed... but if you can report the new results now, they'll be able to judge what might still need to be fixed in the next patch.

Comment: Looks like both sandboxes and production are now up to Patch 10.3.